# Using Html.DisplayFor() outside of view or getting formatted property from DisplayFormat annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations

I have a utility class with a method to which I'm calling and passing an object from a view. I need to call `Html.DisplayFor()` from within that method or simply need a way to get the property of my model formatted by the `DisplayFormat` data annotation.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMMM d, yyyy}")]
System.DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
```

Is there any way to achieve this outside of a view? I've tried things like passing my `HtmlHelper` object to the method:

```
public static string GetProductSnippet(Product product, HtmlHelper<List<Product>> helper)
{
    return helper.DisplayFor(p => p.ReleaseDate).ToString();
}
```

But this won't work, as my `HtmlHelper` object will not always have the same generic type. Is there some way to get the formatted version of a property without using the `HtmlHelper` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generic type for the method:

```
public static string GetProductSnippet<T>(Product product, HtmlHelper<T> helper)
{
    return helper.DisplayFor(p => p.ReleaseDate).ToString();
}

var markup = GetProductSnippet<List<Product>>(product, helper);
```

As for getting the code without the helper, you can get the implementation of the display helper from MVC source code and adjust it to your needs

Comment: Cheers! strangely, `GetProductSnippet(product, helper)` seems to work just the same as long as I declare a generic for the method. I guess it's somehow inferred from the `HtmlHelper` object.